# How to perform join correctly

Tags: sql-server, join, concatenation

I have the following problem on performing a left join between 2 tables.

Table SC1

| COMPANY | PEDIDO | ITEM_NUMBER | VALUE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 4789 | 1 | 100 |
| 1 | 4789 | 2 | 120 |

and Table SD1

| COMPANY | PEDIDO | ITEM_NUMBER | DOC_NUMBER |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 7489 | 1 | 5874 |
| 1 | 7489 | 1 | 5875 |
| 1 | 7489 | 2 | 5880 |

I need to bring the Doc_Number to the SC1 table. But when I use left join and there are more than 1 Doc_Number fot the key, it duplicates the result.

Here's the result I'm getting:

| COMPANY | PEDIDO | ITEM_NUMBER | VALUE | DOC_NUMBER |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 7489 | 1 | 100 | 5874 |
| 1 | 7489 | 1 | 100 | 5875 |
| 1 | 7489 | 2 | 120 | 5880 |

The result I want:

| COMPANY | PEDIDO | ITEM_NUMBER | VALUE | DOC NUMBER |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 7489 | 1 | 100 | 5874-5875 |
| 1 | 7489 | 2 | 120 | 5880 |

Here's the code I'm using:

```sql
SELECT COMPANY,
       PEDIDO,
       ITEM_NUMBER,
       VALUE,
       DOC_NUMBER`
FROM SC1
     LEFT JOIN SD1 ON SC1.COMPANY = SD1.COMPANY
                  AND SC1.PEDIDO = SD1.PEDIDO
                  AND SC1.ITEM_NUMBER = SD1.ITEM_NUMBER;
GO
```

Comment: You could group by `COMPANY, PEDIDO, ITEM_NUMBER, VALUE` and then take `CONCAT(MIN(DOC_NUMBER), '-', MAX(DOC_NUMBER))` but your expected results are unclear. Do you only want the first and last, or do you want all the `DOC_NUMBER` aggregated?

Comment: @Charlieface Yes, I want all the DOC_NUMBER related to that key, without duplicating the rows. I tried STRING_AGG but It didnt work with my sql version.

Comment: Then you need to use a correlated subquery with `FOR XML`, as shown in those linked posts